# Encrypting a database password column

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption

I have a table, which looks like this and is used to compose connection strings (there are about 30 records in this table):

```
create table databases (id int not null, databaseserver varchar(30), databasename varchar(30), username varchar(30), password varchar(30), primary key (id))
```

I always read that you should hash passwords in a database.  However, this will not work here because the passwords have to be converted back to text.

How would I approach this? Transparent Data Encryption sounds like the answer.  Am I able to encrypt this column only without having to modify any code that uses the column.

Comment: why do you need the password converted back to text? If you want to compare it to a userinput, just use the same key the original passward was crypted an compare the results.

Comment: @RomanCoo, because password is part of the connection string.

Comment: Yes, but why do you want to store it in a database?  TDE won't help you here - that just encrypts the file the database uses.

Comment: @Dan Field, the previous developer stored the passwords in a database table but did not encrypt them.  I want to encrypt them.

Comment: I'm confused; you're storing database connection strings in a database; that's either chicken and egg, or the primary database has a hardcoded password, or it uses trusted auth.  Use trusted auth everywhere, as Dan says, or quit using a database to store connection strings.

Answer (score 2):

TDE will not solve your problems here - that will only encrypt the database files.  It's not a bad idea, but it won't stop a user with access to the table from reading the passwords.

First, if you have any other options, **do not store connection strings with passwords in a database**.  It's very easy to get something wrong.

- Can you change your authentication scheme to use Trusted Authentication or some kind of SSO?  Do that.  It will likely require less refactoring than trying to encrypt passwords in any sensible manner.  If not..
- Is this for a web app ?  [Store them in web.config and encrypt that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx).  If not...
- Can you require a user to enter a password instead every time?  If so, do that.  Only store the hashed version if you absolutely must for verification.

If none of these will work for you, you'll have to encrypt the data.  You can do that in SQL Server, [MSDN has more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx).  However, if you handle this in the data layer (or more specifically, the database) completely, it may not offer sufficient protection - as long as a request comes in that looks like it contains the right credentials, it will obtain the plaintext password.

If you require each application to know the correct key, you may as well refactor things so that the application just uses trusted connections (and the destination server is configured to properly allow that)...